# Polymorphic type of functions as parameter in haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, types, polymorphism, polymorphic-functions

Im trying to define the polymorphic type of the following function:

```
flip f x y = f y x
```

My thought was the following:

1. 1st parameter of `flip`, **`f`** takes two arguments so `(t1 -> t2 -> t3)`
2. 2nd parameter of `flip`, **`x`** is of type **`t1`** because of the parameter **`t1`** inside **`f`** function.
3. 3rd parameter of `flip`, **`y`** which is of type **`t3`** because of the parameter **`t3`** inside **`f`** function.
4. I don't know the polymorphic type of the overall return.

But when I checked the type in the ghci, I get:

```
flip :: (t2 -> t1 -> t) -> t1 -> t2 -> t
```

Can someone please help go through this example was to whats happening here?

Thanks

Comment: It's obviously flipping the arguments of the function that you feed it with a function which takes `t2` and `t1` types in order by returning the same function which takes `t1` and `t2` types in order..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your **second assumption is wrong**:

> <s>2nd parameter of flip, x is of type t1 because of the parameter t1 inside f function.</s>

Let us first analyze the function:

```
flip f x y = f y x
```

We see that `flip` has three arguments in the head. So we first make the type:

```
flip :: a -> (b -> (c -> d))
```

We will of course now aim to fill in the types. With:

```
f :: a
x :: b
y :: c
flip f x y :: d
```

We see on the right hand side:

```
(f y) x
```

So that means that `f` is a function that takes as input `y`. So that means that `a` is the same type as `c -> e` (or shorter `a ~ c -> e`).

So now:

```
flip :: (c -> e) -> (b -> (c -> d))
f :: (c -> e)
x :: b
y :: c
```

Furthermore we see that:

```
(f x) y
```

So the result of `(f x)` is another function, with as input `y`. So that means that `e ~ b -> f`. Thus:

```
flip :: (c -> (b -> f)) -> (b -> (c -> d))
f :: c -> (b -> f)
x :: b
y :: c
```

Finally we see that `(f y) x` is the result of `flip f x y`. So that means that the type of the result of `(f y) x` is the same type as `d`. So that means that `f ~ d`. Which thus means that:

```
flip :: (c -> (b -> d)) -> (b -> (c -> d))
```

Or if we drop some redundant brackets:

```
flip :: (c -> b -> d) -> b -> c -> d
```

Comment: on the right hand side, how did you determined that f took only y? as in `(f y) x`? i thought on the right hand side, it took the form of `f (y x)`

Comment: @James: that's how Haskell syntax works. If you write `foo bar qux foobar`, you written implicitly `((foo bar) qux) foobar`... Note that in Haskell **every function takes only one argument**.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a matter of solving a system of equations. First, assign unknown types:

```
f : a1
x : a2
y : a3
```

Next, `f` is applied to `y`. So, `f` must be a function type with argument of the same type as y, that is

```
f : a1 = a3 -> a4
f y : a4
```

Similarily, `f y` is applied to `x`, so

```
f y : a4 = a2 -> a5
f y x : a5
```

Substituting this back, we get

```
f : a3 -> a2 -> a5
x : a2
y : a3
```

We can rename these types

```
t2 = a3
t1 = a2
t  = a5
```

and get

```
f : t2 -> t1 -> t
x : t1
y : t2
```

The function body is `f y x`, which has type `t = a5`.

Comment: how did you determine that f only takes y as argument? I thought f took `f (y x)`

Comment: `f y x` is `(f y) x`, not `f (y x)`. This is true throughout all of Haskell, not specific to this function.

Comment: What amalloy said. Also, if you don't know the trick: one can model any n-argument function using only one argument functions provided that functions are first class - that you can return them as results.